# Clear stack or pop stack

Tags: file, batch-file

I am running a .BAT file that makes several calls within itself.  How do I pop a return location from the stack so it doesn't return to the last call location but the one prior to it?

Comment: You really can't do this. You have to return with a flag that you want to return from that function as well. You can't return directly, because the active stack frame, only knows where the bottom of its frame is.

Comment: Set a flag, and return to the last call location.  If the flag is set, return again.

Comment: That's what I was doing.  I was just hoping for a cleaner solution.  Thanks for the help guys!